# Redirect in Nginx variable subdomain

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have a bunch of subdomain `http://product.domain.com` that I would like to redirect to `http://www.domain.com/product`.

Of course, the product name can be different, and the redirect has to be done accordingly.

Any pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try something that could include several subdomains, like this

```
server {
        server_name  ~^(sub1|sub2|sub3|sub4).example.com;
        return 301 $scheme://example.com/$1;
}
```

Comment: looks nice, but can I substitute `(sub1|sub2|sub3|sub4)` by `*` or `(.*)` whichever works?

Comment: ended up with `server_name ~^([a-z0-9]+).example.com;`. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name product.domain.com;

    return 301 http://www.domain.com/product$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: your solution is valid for one product only, I wanted one solution that can work for all sub-domains created and to come.